# How to get latitude and longitude from an address to pass it to react leaflet?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, react-leaflet

react leaflet needs lat and lng to show desired place in the map. How can i calculate that lat and lng from given address? I need the lat and lng of two address.

Should i have to use geocoder and wrap renderMap function inside it? In my code i want lat and lng of cityOrigen and cityDestino.

```
function renderMap(cityOrigen, cityDestino) {
  return <ReactMap crityOrigen={cityOrigen} cityDestino={cityDestino} />;
}

const ReactMap = ({ cityOrigen, cityDestino }) => {
  const position = [51.505, -0.09];
  return (
    <Map center={position} zoom={13} style={{ height: 500 }}>
      <TileLayer
        url='https://mt{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}'
      />
      <Marker position={position}>
        <Popup>
          <span>A pretty CSS3 popup.</span>
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    </Map>
  );
};

class CarResult extends Component {
  render() {
    const { carResult, origen, destino } = this.props;
    const cityOrigen = origen && origen.label.split(', ')[0];
    const cityDestino = destino && destino.label.split(', ')[0];
    const carResultMap = renderMap(cityOrigen, cityDestino);
    if (!carResult.fetching) {
      return (
        <div>
          Hemos encontrado {carResultList.length} ofertas para ti.
          <div className="car-result-container">
            <Grid fluid>
              <Row>
                <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
                  {carResultList}
                </Col>
                <Col x={12} sm={12} md={6}>
                  {carResultMap}
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Grid>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

- in `renderMap` you have `cityOrigen` and the ReactMap component is being passed in `crityOrigen`. I'm sure that's just a typo.
- You can use a Leaflet Geocoder plugin such as [this one](https://github.com/smeijer/L.GeoSearch). You can put that into your `renderMap` function to parse the location (which I assume is `cityDestino` and `cityOrigen`, in address).